# boolean value changes without me coding it in

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int t, n;

    cin >> t;

    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {

        cin >> n;
        vector<vector<int>> numbers;

        for (int k = 1; k < n * n; k += n) {
            vector<int> temp;
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                temp.push_back(k + j);
            }
            numbers.push_back(temp);
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < numbers.size(); j++) //row
            for (int k = 0; k < numbers.size(); k++) { //column
                bool adjacent = false;
                if (j - 1 > 0)
                    if (abs(numbers[j][k] - numbers[j - 1][k]) == 1)
                        adjacent = true;
                if (j + 1 < numbers.size())
                    if (abs(numbers[j][k] - numbers[j + 1][k]) == 1)
                        adjacent = true;
                if (k - 1 > 0)
                    if (abs(numbers[j][k] - numbers[j][k - 1]) == 1)
                        adjacent = true;
                if (k + 1 < numbers.size())
                    if (abs(numbers[j][k] - numbers[j][k + 1]) == 1)
                        adjacent = true;

                if (adjacent)
                    for (int l = 0; l < numbers.size(); l++)
                        for (int m = 0; m < numbers.size(); m++) {
                            bool adjacent2 = false, adjacent3 = false;

                            if (j - 1 > 0)
                                if (abs(numbers[l][m] - numbers[j - 1][k]) == 1)
                                    adjacent2 = true;
                            if (j + 1 < numbers.size())
                                if (abs(numbers[l][m] - numbers[j + 1][k]) == 1)
                                    adjacent2 = true;
                            if (k - 1 > 0)
                                if (abs(numbers[l][m] - numbers[j][k - 1]) == 1)
                                    adjacent2 = true;
                            if (k + 1 < numbers.size())
                                if (abs(numbers[l][m] - numbers[j][k + 1]) == 1) {
                                    adjacent2 = true;
                                    cout << "hi " << adjacent2 << endl; //HERE
                                }

                            if (!adjacent2) {
                                cout << adjacent2 << endl;
                                if (l - 1 > 0)
                                    if (abs(numbers[j][k] - numbers[l - 1][m]) == 1)
                                        adjacent3 = true;
                                if (l + 1 < numbers.size())
                                    if (abs(numbers[j][k] - numbers[l + 1][m]) == 1)
                                        adjacent3 = true;
                                if (m - 1 > 0)
                                    if (abs(numbers[j][k] - numbers[l][m - 1]) == 1)
                                        adjacent3 = true;
                                if (m + 1 < numbers.size())
                                    if (abs(numbers[j][k] - numbers[l][m + 1]) == 1)
                                        adjacent3 = true;
                                if (!adjacent3) {
                                    int temp = numbers[j][k];
                                    numbers[j][k] = numbers[l][m];
                                    numbers[l][m] = temp;
                                }
                            }
                        }
            }   

        if (n > 2)
            for (auto x : numbers) {
                for (int y : x) {
                    cout << y << " ";
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
        else if (n == 1)
            cout << 1 << endl;
        else cout << -1 << endl;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to solve this codeforces problem: https://codeforces.com/contest/1520/problem/C. The way I'm trying to solve it is by generating a 2d array from 1 to n squared. I then start from the first row, left to right, and work my way down to the last number. For each element, in the 2d array, I check for adjacent elements and see if their differences are equal to one. If there's at least one instance of that, I search for an element that can be swapped with the original element.

Swapping the elements works correctly, except for the first one.

For example, if n = 3, I should start with:

123 
456 
789

and then I should get

423 
156 
789

However, I get

213 
456 
789

It doesn't matter if n=3 or n=10. It will always start as 213...

I tried debugging and noticed that in the line denoted as "HERE", adjacent2 is true. However, the next if-statement, if(!adjacent2) runs. Why does it run? If adjacent2 is true, shouldn't !adjacent2 equal false?  I also printed out adjacent2 after if(!adjacent2) and it's somehow false and I never changed it!

Comment: Are you sure in the same iteration? Since you have no `cout` at the end of loop containing these 2 `if`s, you may see first "HERE" in an iteration and `if(!adjacent2)` runs in next iteration. This may happen if you debugging with `cout`. Try add another `cout` at end of loop to see it is shown between printing "HERE" and running `if(!adjacent2)`.

Comment: @kesarlingHe-Him those 2 are equal...

Comment: @Afshin, sorry... don't know what I was thinking Is it possible that the comparison between signed and unsigned is causing undefined behaviour?

Comment: hmm, can't reproduce.. 813 246 579...

Comment: Please do the debugging experiment proposed above and report (preferrably with updated [mre]).

Comment: OK - It's not one of the best ever questions asked on SO, bit neither does it lack details. I'm *not* voting to close!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this part might not be correct:

```
if (k + 1 < numbers.size())
    if (abs(numbers[j][k] - numbers[j][k + 1]) == 1)
        adjacent = true;
```

If the matrix is not square, `numbers.size()` might not be the same as `numbers[j].size()`. And then `k + 1` should be compared to the latter.